# How to solve issue with HttpGet on Android?

Tags: java, android

I wrote code to make get request on Android, but I error like this:

```
07-07 21:12:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(2409):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
```

So I read I have to use AsyncTask. I did it. One time it worked well, but next time I run app and I had that error again.

This is my code:

```
package app.teksty;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private class HttpGetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>
    {

        private InputStream content;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

              String url = params[0];
              Log.i("[GET REQUEST]", "STARTED");
              try {
                  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
                  content = response.getEntity().getContent();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception", e);
              }

              return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { 
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            StringBuilder respond = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {

                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    respond.append(line);
                }

                Log.i("[GET REQUEST]", respond.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.e("[GET REQUEST]", "", e);
            }

        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new HttpGetRequest().execute("http://www.google.pl");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

What I did wrong or what I have to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to show more of the error output. Show the entire chunk of red error text if possible. The solution may depend entirely on the type of error it is (not just where it occurs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're are working on main thread while working with Inputstream, and that counts as working on network. Read the whole content in doInBackground() handler, and you should be fine

Answer (score 6):

Try putting this code in your method `onCreate()`:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

However this works only for build sdk version 9 and greater

Comment: you forgot and s on new trictMode?

Answer (score 0):

The `onPostExecute()` method runs on main UI thread. You are not using any UI element in it, so why to have all those statements in UI thread. Just move all those statements into `doInBackground()` at the end, before return statement and try if that works.